# Rails 3: Get current namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, actioncontroller

using a method :layout_for_namespace I set my app's layout depending on whether I am in frontend or backend, as the backend is using an namespace "admin".

I could not find a pretty way to find out which namespace I am, the only way I found is by parsing the string from params[:controller]. Of course that's easy, seems to be fail-safe and working good. But I am just wondering if there's a better, prepared, way to do this. Does anyone know?

Currently I am just using the following method:

```
def is_backend_namespace?
  params[:controller].index("admin/") == 0
end
```

Thanks in advance

Arne

Answer (score 45):

You can use:

```
self.class.parent == Admin
```

Comment: this answer should be first one!

Comment: As many have pointed out this doesn't work for classes that have multiple levels of namespacing. However if you are just checking to see if you are in such a namespace (like the OP kind of was getting at) then you can use `controller.class.parents.include?(Admin)` and get at the similar thing without having to resort to string parsing

Comment: @trcarden I get this error with that solution: `NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method 'controller'`. I'm on Rails 5.1. `self.class.parents` works and is equivalent.

Answer (score 27):

Outside the controller (e.g. in the views), use controller.class.name. You can turn this into a helper method like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def admin?
    controller.class.name.split("::").first=="Admin"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a simple and easy to use solution, especially when you need to check the namespace in `Views`.

Comment: also in the views you can use controller.class.parent.name

Comment: how to call this from the view?

Comment: looks like dirty code... I think more clear to use class.parent

Answer (score 20):

In both the controller and the views, you can parse controller_path, eg.:

```
namespace = controller_path.split('/').first
```

Comment: this gives `'foo'` back if I say `'foo'.split('/').first` . A solution would be best if namespace is `nil` when checking a non-namespaced controller name

Answer (score 11):

Not much more elegant, but it uses the class instead of the params hash.  I am not aware of a "prepared" way to do this without some parsing.

```
self.class.to_s.split("::").first=="Admin"
```

Comment: Hi. That's not what I meant, sorry. The controller's name is something else, "admin" is the namespace. It's Admin::MyController, so params[:controller] gives "admin/my_controller" or something, thats where I check if it is the admin namespace. Using controller_name I would have to do just the same, but I'd like to know a way to not _parse_ it but get back the namespace only.

Comment: My fault, I didn't read the question closely.  You clearly state namespace and not controller name.  Answer updated with an alternative.

Comment: More simply `controller.class.name.start_with?('Admin')`.

Answer (score 10):

Setting the namespace in application controller:

```
path = self.controller_path.split('/')
@namespace = path.second ? path.first : nil
```

Comment: This would obviate the ternary:  @namespace = (path.first if path.second)

Answer (score 10):

None of these solutions consider a constant with multiple parent modules.  For instance:

```
A::B::C
```

As of Rails 3.2.x you can simply:

```
"A::B::C".deconstantize #=> "A::B"
```

As of Rails 3.1.x you can:

```
constant_name = "A::B::C"
constant_name.gsub( "::#{constant_name.demodulize}", '' )
```

This is because #demodulize is the opposite of #deconstantize:

```
"A::B::C".demodulize #=> "C"
```

If you really need to do this manually, try this:

```
constant_name = "A::B::C"
constant_name.split( '::' )[0,constant_name.split( '::' ).length-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

In **Rails 6**, the controller class does not seem to have a `namespace` method on it.

The solution that seemed cleanest and worked for me in a view was: `controller.class.module_parent`

Specifically, if your namespace is Admin:: and you wanted 'admin', you'd do:
`controller.class.module_parent.to_s.downcase`

Comment: Seems like module_parent is not available yet in Rails 6.0.3.2. So, I use `controller.class.parent`

Comment: This doesn't work if you have nested controllers
```
Admin::Accounts::SubAccountsController
```
gives you
```
Admin::Accounts
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 6**

Accessing the namespace in the view?

do not use: `controller.namespace.parent == Admin`

the `parent` method will be removed in Rails 6.1

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `Module#parent` has been renamed to `module_parent`. `parent` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1.
```

use `module_parent` instead:

`controller.namespace.module_parent == Admin`

Comment: Tried `controller.namespace`, but it says undefined method 'namespace'. I used rails 6.0 and `controller.class.parent` works

Comment: For me `controller.class.module_parent` worked

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6 you can do:

```
controller.class.module_parent
```

to get the parent module. Haven't tried it with multiple nestings. But for one you can convert to a symbol like this:

```
controller.class.module_parent.to_s.underscore.to_sym
```