# Rails 4: Get current namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What is the way to know if i'm currently inside a namespaced route?

I can't belive there is a method or something defined for this

what i'm doing right now

```
@admin_namespace = self.class.name.start_with? 'Admin'
```

Is this the right solution?

Comment: I can't believe i didn't find a duplicate for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3: Get current namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226573/rails-3-get-current-namespace)

Comment: But thats for rails 3.

Comment: Solution in the link I provided worked for Rails 3, works in Rails 4 and will work in Rails 5 :) (it is actually Ruby, nothing Rails-specific)

Comment: I know it works, but there is no a rails method to get this?